# validate sms template using preg_match

Tags: php, html, sms, preg-match

I want to validate content against the pattern. The pattern has got multiple variable. Each variable is of 30 characters. To increase the length of the variable we repeat `{#var#}` multiple times.
`preg_match` helped me when both content and pattern were static strings. Now, I am facing difficulty when I try to pass the dynamic content.

```
content = Dear customer, your otp is e9(3>D5. Thanks

pattern = Dear customer, your otp is {#var#}. Thanks
```

This is the code I tried with, but no success when added variables. Looking for only php or javascript code

```
$content = '#Dear customer, your otp is e9(3>D5. Thanks#';
$pattern = '#Dear customer, your otp is <input type="text" id="otp" name="otp" value="" maxlength="30">. Thanks#';

echo preg_match($pattern, $content);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: What are the rules for your pattern?

Comment: Why are you including static content in the preg_match input?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson only on successful match of static in content and pattern, sms will be sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:
`/#Dear customer, your otp is ([a-zA-Z0-9()<>.]{1,30}) Thanks#/`